# Is there any way to call a python script which is inside EC2 instance using AWS managed airflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, airflow

I have to connect ec2 instance with aws managed airflow. For this I have created a dag file in aws managed airflow which is having following callable function to run script inside ec2 instance.
I have referred this link
[to run a python script that is located on the aws ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102898/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-that-is-located-on-the-aws-ec2-server)

[Here is link to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/walkthrough-cli.html#walkthrough-cli-example-1)

The dag that I have created is having the following python callable function:

```
def conn():
   ssm = boto3.client('ssm',aws_access_key_id="xxxxyyyy",aws_secret_access_key="xxxyyyy",region_name="xz")
   response = ssm.send_command(InstanceIds=['xyzzy'], DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript', Comment='running email test',Parameters={"commands":["sh python_script.sh"]})
```

The above command is not running the shell script. But if I write touch abc.txt, this command is able to create a text file.
Is there any reason why text file is getting created but the python script/shell script is not running?

Comment: Did you check the [SSM Agent logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-agent-logs.html)? I wonder whether you could also redirect output to a log to view any error messages? eg `sh python_script.sh >>/tmp/python_script.log`

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. But it has created an empty log file.